# iterate through html class and assign each value to variables

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domxpath

Im building a small website that grabs values from a directory and places it Google Maps.

So basically it grabs the name, address, telephone and the url. Im trying to use php and xpath to grab each values and assign them to separate variables so i can echo it in my page.

```
<div class="listing">

  <div data-company="" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" itemscope="" class="l-container clearfix">


  <div class="l-header clearfix">
    <h2 class="cypher">
      <a itemprop="name" href="/company/profile/574">
        The Company
      </a>
    </h2>

  </div>
  <div class="l-footer clearfix">

    <div class="l-telephone">

      <ul>
        <li class="last" data-company-item="telephone">
          Texas: 
          <strong>
            12345 6789
          </strong>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <ul class="l-link clearfix">

      <li>
        <a data-company-item="visiturl" href="http://www.mywebsite.com" target="_blank"  class="l-link-w clearfix">
          Visit 

        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

this is my xpath code in php.

```
   $elements = $xpath->query("//div[@class='listing']//a[@itemprop='name']|//a[@itemprop='address']|//ul/li[@data-company-item='telephone']|//a[@data-company-item='visiturl']");
```

The problem that im having is when i iterate through the values, i need to assign them to variables.

```
   foreach($elements as $element)
   {
      //$name=
      //$address=
      //$phone = 
     //$url=
   }
```

the display will be

```
Company Name: ABC  
Address: Some Address  
Telephone: 123456789 
Website: yourdomain.com
```

i tried the below code

```
   foreach($elements as $element)
   {
        echo $element->nodeValue(0);
        echo "<br>";


   }
```

it displays all the values but i need to assign each value to a variable. can someone please tell me how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use an associative array.

Define it like this outside the loop

```
$storedElements = array();
```

then inside your loop simply do

```
$storedElements[$element]=$element->nodeValue(0);
```

should deliver the desired result.

After that you can access them like this

```
foreach($storedElement as $element=>$id)
    echo 'id: '.$id.' | element: '.$element."\n";
```

HTH

J.